# C# Get Variable Value from Separate Form

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get the values of variables from a separate form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can expose them through [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

For example, if form Form2 has a variable named `_Count` of type `int`, you can create a property like this:

```
public int Count
{
    get { return _Count; }
}
```

Then you can access that property on Form2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the following code in the other form if you want to get a specific value of a variable for instance a textbox... Note that the variable text is declared to who will receive the value and that it is static.

```
public Form2(string text)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     text = textBox.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in your values in an overloaded constructor of your instantiated form.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read the values of few variables you can go with the solution provided by CesarGon.

Its simple you can get the values of properties like Form2.Count and so on...while your form is not disposed.

You can create a method returning Hashtable which will contain the values you want to return.
for example

```
public Hashtable GetData()
{
     Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
     ht.add('count',textBox1.Text);

     return ht;
}
```

If you want to pass values of one form to another form you can pass them from the constructor of second form.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the other form is running and the variable is accessible (public) that you just need to pass the reference to the form.

Comment: Public fields (variables) are not good practice. Use a property instead (see my answer).